# How does Windows pass the ANSI command line when creating a process?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, command-line, process

During process initialization, Windows sets up the [PEB structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which includes, among other things, a structure `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS` which in turn points to the UNICODE version of the command line.
You can also access it using `GetCommandLineW`.

`GetCommandLineA` returns the ANSI version and (obviously) points to a different address.

My question is, does windows initialize the two versions during process creation, and which data structure, if any, points to the ANSI version of the command line? Also, is there a way other than calling GetCommandLineA to retrieve it?

Thanks

Comment: There is [likely] no ANSI version stored anywhere. Windows translates the Unicode version to ANSI when you request the ANSI version.

Comment: actually, there is an ANSI version. steping into the assembly of GetCommandLineA confirms it

Comment: What's wrong with `GetCommandLineA`?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious There has to be an ANSI version stored somewhere. Look at the prototype for `GetCommandLineA`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm trying to dynamically create a different command-line for a process. It is part of a research I'm conducting regarding process creation and executable file format.

Comment: You'll need to reverse engineer all the versions of Windows that you need to support.

Comment: The ANSI version is created automatically on process startup. It's stored at the address that `GetCommandLineA` returns :)

Answer (score 4):

I disassembled Kernel32 on Windows 7 and see that during process startup, it accesses the Unicode command line in the process's `PEB` and stores a pointer to that character data in a variable that `GetCommandLineW()` returns.  It also converts that Unicode data to a separate Ansi buffer which `GetCommandLineA()` returns a pointer to.  As near as I can tell, the Ansi buffer is private to the Kernel module, it is not stored in the `PEB`, so it is unlikely that you will be able to access the Ansi buffer across process boundaries like you can with the Unicode buffer.

Comment: Thanks Remy! Do you know if Windows set the pointer to the ANSI buffer in a known fixed address ?